# How to retrieve video including paid promotion by YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api, youtube-analytics-api

We want to retrieve video data including promotions.
Is there a way to get it with the YouTube Data API or the YouTube Analytics API?
Is there any other way?

A video that includes a promotion is a video that displays something like the image below.

[image]

Click to move to the following page.

https://support.google.com/youtube/answer/154235

Comment: Knowing whether or not (boolean result) the video includes paid promotion is this enough for you ?

Comment: @BenjaminLoison Yes, I would like to collect data only for videos with promotions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you are only interested in knowing whether or not a video (based on its id) includes paid promotion, as far as I know there isn't any official YouTube Data API v3 endpoint answering your question.

However you can check if the video includes paid promotion by checking whether or not the YouTube webpage contains `paidContentOverlayRenderer`. You can proceed this way for instance:

```bash
curl -s https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=VIDEO_ID | grep "paidContentOverlayRenderer"
```

If something is returned it means that the video includes paid promotion otherwise it doesn't.

Another similar answer that I have written is available [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71789358).