# Check "paid product" flag via YouTube API

Tags: youtube-api, youtube-data-api

Is there any way to set "paid product" flag to true on video via Youtube API?

Comment: Does [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71789358/7123660) answer your question?

Comment: No, I need to set the flag, not only read it

Comment: "check" term was ambiguous. As YouTube Data API v3 [Videos: Insert#request-body](https://developers.google.com/youtube/v3/docs/videos/insert#request-body) doesn't contain a "paid product" field, it doesn't seem feasible.